# Backpropagation in python: numpy array multiplication mistake?

Tags: python, numpy, deep-learning, backpropagation, sigmoid

I am currently trying to do backpropagation on the function f(x,W) = ||sigmoid(Wx)||^2 where W is a 3x3 matrix, x is a 3x1 matrix, and sigmoid performs the element-wise sigmoid function (1/1-e^x). Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
from math import *



#forward pass
W = np.array([[0.1, 0.5, 0.2],[-0.3, 0.8, 0.5],[0.5,0.2,0.3]])
x = np.array([[0.2],[0.4],[0.1]])
q = np.dot(W,x)
sig = np.round(1 / (1 + np.exp(-q)), 3)
loss = np.round(np.sum(sig**2), 3)
f = loss

print('type W:',type(W))
print('shape W:',W.shape)
print('\ntype x:',type(x))
print('shape x:',x.shape)
print('\ntype q:',type(q))
print('shape q:',q.shape)
print('\ntype sig:',type(sig))
print('shape sig:',sig.shape)
print('\ntype Loss:',type(loss))
print('shape Loss:',loss.shape)

#print forward pass values
print('\nValues of forward pass:')
print('q:\n', np.round(q, 3))
print('sig:\n', np.round(sig, 3))
print('L2 Loss:',f)

#backward pass
#backprop f = loss: df/loss = 1
df_df = 1
#backprop loss = np.sum(sig*sig): (dloss/dsig)(df/df) 
df_dsig = 2*sig*df_df
#backprop sig = 1 / 1 + np.exp(-q): (dsig/dq)(df/dsig)
dsig_dq = ((1 - sig)*sig)*df_dsig
#backprop q = np.dot(W,x): (dq/dW)(dsig/dq)(df/dsig)
df_dW = np.round((x.T)*(dsig_dq)*(df_dsig), 3)
df_dx = np.round((2*W.T)*(dsig_dq)*(df_dsig), 3)

print('\ndf_dsig:', df_dsig)

print('\ntype df/dsig:', type(df_dsig))
print('shape df/dsig:', df_dsig.shape)
print('\ntype dsig/dq:', type(dsig_dq))
print('shape dsig/dq:', dsig_dq.shape)
print('\ntype df/dW:', type(df_dW))
print('shape df/dW:', df_dW.shape)
print('\ntype df/dx:', type(df_dx))
print('shape df/dx:', df_dx.shape)
print('\ntype dsig_dq*df_dsig:', type(dsig_dq*df_dsig))
print('shape dsig_dq*df_dsig:', (dsig_dq*df_dsig).shape)

#print backprop values
print('\nValues of backpropagation:')
print(np.round(df_dsig, 3))
print(np.round(dsig_dq, 3))
#printing gradient values of f(x,W) with respect to x_i and W_i,j
print('\nGradients of f(x,W) are:')
print('df/dW:\n', df_dW)
print('df/dx:\n', df_dx)
```

This prints out:

```
type W: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
shape W: (3, 3)

type x: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
shape x: (3, 1)

type q: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
shape q: (3, 1)

type sig: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
shape sig: (3, 1)

type Loss: <class 'numpy.float64'>
shape Loss: ()

Values of forward pass:
q:
 [[0.24]
 [0.31]
 [0.21]]
sig:
 [[0.56 ]
 [0.577]
 [0.552]]
L2 Loss: 0.951

df_dsig: [[1.12 ]
 [1.154]
 [1.104]]

type df/dsig: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
shape df/dsig: (3, 1)

type dsig/dq: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
shape dsig/dq: (3, 1)

type df/dW: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
shape df/dW: (3, 3)

type df/dx: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
shape df/dx: (3, 3)

type dsig_dq*df_dsig: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
shape dsig_dq*df_dsig: (3, 1)

Values of backpropagation:
[[1.12 ]
 [1.154]
 [1.104]]
[[0.276]
 [0.282]
 [0.273]]

Gradients of f(x,W) are:
df/dW:
 [[0.062 0.124 0.031]
 [0.065 0.13  0.033]
 [0.06  0.121 0.03 ]]
df/dx:
 [[ 0.062 -0.185  0.309]
 [ 0.325  0.52   0.13 ]
 [ 0.121  0.301  0.181]]
```

I'm printing out the type and shape of everything so it's easier for me and everyone to understand. But looking at the lines:

```
df_dW = np.round((x.T)*(dsig_dq)*(df_dsig), 3)
df_dx = np.round((2*W.T)*(dsig_dq)*(df_dsig), 3)
```

There is surely something wrong here. I think i am coincidentally getting both as 3x3 matrices, but the backpropagation of df_dW should be a 3x3 and df_dx should be a 3x1, just like the original input parameters. I have no idea why i'm getting them both as 3x3, but I figured it could be in the sig equation. I've been at this for so many hours, hopefully someone could please help me out here and fix my mistake. Thank you!

Comment: Your derivatives are shape `(3,1)` and so is `x`, so `x.T` is `(1,3)`, so broadcasting gets you `(3,3)`. Do you need the `.T` in `x.T`?

Comment: I also don't see where the factor of 2 difference is coming from between `df/dx` and `df/dW`. Also make sure it's `W.T` and not `W` in the derivative.